# Send header in get request using Laravel Http Client

Tags: laravel, http-headers, httpclient

I want to send Header using Http Client in get() method, let me share my code with you.

```
Http::get('https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/plans')->withHeader(['Authorization', $zohoToken]);
```

I want to pass these headers but don't know how to pass headers in http::get() request

```
$header = array(
         'Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken ' . $accessToken,
         'Content-Type: application/json' );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use here [withHeaders](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#headers) method

```
Http::withHeaders([
     'Authorization' =>  'Zoho-oauthtoken ' . $accessToken,
     'Content-Type' => 'application/json' 
])->get('https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/plans');
```

Comment: I used this method earlier but it's not passing the token. In PostMan, my logic is working but In HTTP it's not working, return invalid auth token, Is there any way to check that headers are properly set.

Comment: I dd() the authorization header it's not set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  Http::withToken()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31611979)

Comment: For anybody looking: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client#bearer-tokens

Bearer Tokens
If you would like to quickly add a bearer token to the request's Authorization header, you may use the withToken method:

`$response = Http::withToken('token')->post(/* ... */);`